# Referenced component does not update until restart visual studio 2015 update 2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, design-time, component-design

**Description:**

I have two projects(for example); First project contains one Component class with `[ToolBoxItem(true)]` attribute added; Second project reference first project and uses designed component of First project.

Now, When I make any changes in component class, I need to restart visual studio to unload loaded component dll file.

I find the location of loaded references at `%appdata%/Local/Microsoft/Visual Studio/14.0/ProjectAssemblies/;` But, Until the visual studio process is running, I cannot remove content of that folder.

**Question**

I have a solution file that contains 39 projects and I need to change source code of some projects and view updated source code of components in executable projects.

**How can I do the above job without restarting the visual studio?** (Probably, a command in visual studio command window)